# USB Mouse Pushing to Left

Tags: logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse

I have a wireless Logitech "laser" mouse that is pushing to the left. If I am on a screen with a left-right scroll, and scroll to the right, the screen jumps back to the left. If I do alt+tab to see my open programs, I can see the icons being highlighted one after another from right to left, right to left, never stopping, as if the mouse is being moved to the left and never stopping... but if I leave the mouse sitting, the pointer does not move to the left.

If I unplug the USB dongle, it stops.

I have tried resetting the mouse but it makes no difference.

Ideas?

Comment: if possible, could you please try another mouse and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: Also, do you know what model the Logitech mouse is?

Comment: The problem does not exist when we use a different mouse, so it is definitely the mouse.

Comment: So, it is an optical mouse?  Is the surface "weird" (mirror, glass, something else that might have a homogeneous surface), or might there be a hair or something in the sensor area that might be causing the behavior?